# solr group count giving wrong count

Tags: solr

I am using solr4 and i have some issue in grouping that. here is the query i used for grouping

```
http://****/solr.war/collection1/select?q=name%3Awhat%26a%26girl%26wants&fl=name%2Cprice%2Cupc&wt=xml&indent=true&group=true&group.ngroups=true&group.facet=true&group.field=upc&group.sort=price+asc
```

this is the o/p for that

```
<lst>
    <str name="groupValue">085391170112</str>
    <result name="doclist" numFound="1" start="0">
      <doc>
        <str name="name">What a Girl Wants/Chasing Liberty - DVD</str>
        <str name="upc">085391170112</str>
        <float name="price">9.99</float></doc>
    </result>
  </lst>
  <lst>
```

the 'numFound' is 1 here but when i copy that 'upc' and searched it using the following query

```
http://*****/solr.war/collection1/select?q=upc%3A085391170112&fl=name%2Cupc&wt=xml&indent=true
```

.

```
<result name="response" numFound="2" start="0">
  <doc>
    <str name="name">What a Girl Wants/Chasing Liberty - DVD</str>
    <str name="upc">085391170112</str></doc>
  <doc>
    <str name="upc">085391170112</str>
    <str name="name">Sergio Vitier - Visiones Temas Para Cine</str></doc>
</result>
```

the '`numFound`' is 2 in the upc search.

**my schema is**

```
<field name="upc" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first query,

```
http://****/solr.war/collection1/select?q=name%3Awhat%26a%26girl%26wants&fl=name%2Cprice%2Cupc&wt=xml&indent=true&group=true&group.ngroups=true&group.facet=true&group.field=upc&group.sort=price+asc
```

you got numFound = 1 because, your query

> **q=name%3Awhat%26a%26girl%26wants**

matches only the following doc based on name **( not based on "upc" )**

```
  <doc>
    <str name="name">What a Girl Wants/Chasing Liberty - DVD</str>
    <str name="upc">085391170112</str></doc>
  </doc>
```

On the other hand, in your second query,

```
http://*****/solr.war/collection1/select?q=upc%3A085391170112&fl=name%2Cupc&wt=xml&indent=true
```

you have searched for "upc" which matches all documents with the given "upc" and this does not filter the results for **name:what%26a%26girl%26wants**.

So obviously, the counts will be different as you have two different result sets for your 2 queries.

Comment: thanks for spotting me the issue. is there a way to sort the product inside the group depends upon price ex. if a product upc is same and i have to group it and display a product which has least price i used 'group.sort=price+asc' for that but i cant get the low price in that.

Comment: Even if you give 'group.sort=price+asc', the results which match your query ("q") will only be returned and the lowest price among matched result is returned. You cannot get the lowest of all prices, if it doesn't match your query.